# Convert CLLocationSpeed to long in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I’m trying to get GPS speed in Swift. I've set everything up and am now trying to do some calculations. I want to convert the MS "string" to KMH. So I'm trying to convert the type to long, but I can’t get it to work.

I have tried this:

```
var ms: long?
ms = LocationManager.location.speed
```

But I got "CLLocationspeed is not convertible to long”

I’m new to iOS programming and Swift so I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should really start by reading the [Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/), however:

`long` isn’t a standard type in Swift (not sure where you’ve managed to find one :).  An appropriate integer type to use would be `Int` (unless exact size matters to you – but it probably doesn’t).  But CLLocationSpeed in CoreLocation is a typealias for `Double` and you should probably stick with that for speed calculations.

In Swift, most conversions between types do not happen implicitly.  If you really wanted a `Double` to become an `Int`, you need to explicitly convert it i.e. `let ms = Int(LocationManager.location.speed)`.

This feels like a pain when you are coming from C-like languages.  But there are good reasons behind it.  For example, what should happen to the fractional part of the floating-point number when you assign it to an integer type?  Might you have forgotten your function is returning a floating point number and have accidentally introduced a truncation bug?

To make up for this, Swift also has type inference.  So unless you want to explicitly control the types, you don’t even have to give them:

```
// type of ms is automatically inferred to be CLLocationSpeed (alias for Double)
let ms = LocationManager.location.speed
// 3.6 floating-point literal is automatically converted to appropriate type
// type and kph is automatically a Double
let kph = ms * 3.6
```

Most of the time you don’t need to give a type, just leave it to be inferred it from the context.

Answer (score 0):

Swift does not have a long datatype.

[CLLocationSpeed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CLLocationSpeed) is just a typealias for Double in Swift

So if you want to convert it into Double, do this

```
var ms = Double(LocationManager.location.speed)
```

The Swift compiler will automatically figure out the type for the variable

and then you can substitute Double(value) with Int, Float or any other Swift datatype
to typecast the value.